# Not-able to click the Tab Using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver

Please check the image for issue description

[image: description in image]

Iam not able to click the **Get** tab in Screen. Can some one please help me regarding this. I tried all sorts of findElement (**WebDriver's**) methods, but no luck.

1) By default li class name is `ui-state-default ui-corner-top` for tab.

**HTML Code**

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
<a href="#Init_Get_Grid">Get</a>
</li>
```

2) When mouse hover the tab li class name is change to "ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-state-hover"

**HTML Code**

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-state-hover">
<a href="#Init_Get_Grid">Get</a>
</li>
```

3)When i Click the Tab class name change to `ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active`

**HTML Code**

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
<a href="#Init_Get_Grid">Get</a>
</li>
```

Comment: What WebDriver code have you tried? Are you receiving any particular exceptions etc?

Comment: I want to help you out, but couldn't find with what have you tried upon?

Comment: Did U know how to change frames ???

Comment: i guess your get tab is inside a i frame

Answer (score 0):

Try using XPath to locate your tab:

```
WebElement tab = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='#Init_Get_Grid']"));
tab.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since it is a Jquery tab, i don't known how to click that tab, i already trieded with the above code but no luck... Can you able to help me for Clicking the Jquery Tab.....

Answer (score 0):

There could be two solutions to this problem.

1. If the tab is not in the frame, then use below code to identify the element.

   `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='Get']")).click();`
2. If the tab is inside the frame, then first you need to switch to that particular frame and then perform above action. Please go through the [link](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-work-with-iframes-in-selenium-webdriver) on how to switch between frames, if you are not familiar

Hope this helps.